# Why will a mule app not load postgres driver class for log4j?

Tags: postgresql, log4j, mule, mule-studio

I'm configuring a mule app with log4j to use org.postgresql.Driver.  Below is some of my log4j.properties config.

```
log4j.appender.postgres=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.postgres.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.postgres.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.postgres.URL=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/edus-esb
log4j.appender.postgres.user=<username>
log4j.appender.postgres.password=<password>
log4j.appender.postgres.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%x','%d','%C','%p','%m')
```

According to the logs, everything for the log4j config loads except the driver.

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to load driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I'm using maven to load the appropriate driver using the dependency below, but I've also tried adding the driver manually to the class path via Eclipse -> build path -> add external JARS.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

No luck in either case.  I've had some trouble loading classes in mule projects before, so I wonder if this has something to do with Mule's particular class loading strategy/implementation.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting this error when deploying the application in a Mule standalone instance? 
If that's the case, then copy the jar containing that class to lib/boot in your standalone instance.

Comment: Thanks, Seba.  I'm working in Mule Studio at the moment.  I tried adding a boot directory under lib, and included the driver but no luck.  I also tried dropping the driver in the existing lib/shared/ and lib/shared/default directories.  Still nothing.  I could try deploying to a standalone server not associated with Mule Studio, but that wouldn't explain why I can't get it to work in Studio.

Comment: Ahhhh, I found the mule/boot directory you are talking about.  I was originally looking for it in the .mule/lib dir under the eclipse workspace where the apps are deployed in Studio.  When I didn't see it there I tried creating it.  I eventually found the directory you intended under the plugins dir in my eclipse install (plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0.ee_3.4.0.201305131832\mule\boot).  I added the driver there and it worked!  Thanks!  Now I'm curious whether this is documented anywhere in the official docs...

Comment: You got it right. A good pointer to know from where the Studio libraries are being picked up is to run something like this: ps ax | grep Studio. As for